# Task Automation With .EXE program and Bash Script?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, x11, wine

There's a Windows program called [Visipics](http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page). It finds similar images, not merely duplicates. I find it superior to [findimagedupes](http://www.jhnc.org/findimagedupes/) (I use it with Manjaro and Linux Mint) and competing Windows programs, and it works well with Wine.

But can I run Visipics in a bash script and have it perform a series of operations on images (as detailed in the pic below) without having to open the program and click the buttons myself?

[image: Visipics]

Comment: Are you running this on a Unix machine?  Or on a windows machine?

Comment: I'm running Visipics through Wine on Linux. The tricky thing is running it through a bash script, as I can run it fine with Wine on Linux and natively on Windows. I want all the actions performed through the bash script, without having to open up the program myself and click the buttons.

Comment: have a look at 'gnee' it might be able to perform those GUI actions.

Comment: @Jasen Tx. I just had a look at it, and it got me looking at other screen recorders. I installed a similar program called xmacro through the Arch User Repository.  I followed StackExhange member [Mark's instructions](http://superuser.com/questions/46376/a-good-keyboard-macro-program-for-ubuntu) to make the program work with keyboard hotkeys, and it does work. Now I'll have to play around with it a bit to see if it can work with a series of operations from a bash script.

Comment: xnee can (gnee is xnee with a gtk-based gui), use gnee to record and xnee for command-line playback.  I have not looked at xmacro,

Comment: @jasen, that's a good answer - you should post it as one.

Comment: @Jasen I'm using gnee right now and may choose it over xmacro. Manjaro has Xnee in its software database and gnee is included.